# SQL - Crear una matriz de coincidencias

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

Buenas tardes,
Esta pregunta sería el siguiente paso a la pregunta formulada en "**Duda en sql compleja de agrupación**" y que ya se obtuvo solución.

La resumo e indico la nueva pregunta.

Tengo una tabla con tickets como ésta, sin campo identificador de ticket como tal pero se podría tomar como identificador la fecha + id Cliente. En un mismo color aparecen los artículos del mismo ticket:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La tarea inicial era saber para cada artículo, la suma de veces que se han comprado otros en el mismo ticket.

Gracias al usuario **Marcos Crispino** he dado con la sql que quería hacer:

```
select A.articulo_id, A.articulo_desc, count(*) as total
from tickets_prueba A
where exists (select *
          from tickets_prueba B
          where B.articulo_id = 1
            and A.fecha_ticket_id = B.fecha_ticket_id
            and A.cliente_id = B.cliente_id)
and A.articulo_id <> 1
group by A.articulo_id
```

Ésto saca, para el artículo "Caramelo Fresa" La siguiente tabla:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es decir, cuando se ha comprado el Caramelo Fresa, también se han comprado dos veces los de plátano, y otras dos veces los de coco.

Bien, ahora necesitaría extender esto para todos los artículos, a través de una matriz de productos, en la cual, en cada celda, aparezca el sumatorio de veces que un producto Y de una columna ha sido comprado conjuntamente con un producto X de una fila, o viceversa. Debería sacar algo como ésto:

```
           Articulo_1   Articulo_2  Articulo_3
Articulo_1     0           2            2
Articulo_2     2           0            1
Articulo_3     2           1            0
```

La tabla real sobre la que quiero hacer la query tiene 85 productos diferentes, y si lo intento hacer con 85 queries unidas con UNION, se queda en un bucle infinito, necesitaría hacer algo más optimizado. Además esto no lo saca en formato "Matriz" sino en un listado como la segunda imagen, y luego tendría que  trasponerlo en excel.

¿Alguna idea? Muchas gracias.

P.D. Añado algunas cosas que he hecho:

```
CREATE TABLE prueba as
select * from (
(select (select distinct articulo_id from tickets_yogures b where articulo_id=178342) as articulo_principal, a.articulo_id, a.articulo_desc, (round(count(*)/8)) from tickets_yogures a, tickets_yogures b where exists (select *  from tickets_yogures b  where b.articulo_id = 178342 and a.fecha_ticket_id = b.fecha_ticket_id  and a.cliente_id = b.cliente_id)  and a.articulo_id <>178342 group by a.articulo_id) union 
(select (select distinct articulo_id from tickets_yogures b where articulo_id=165506) as articulo_principal, a.articulo_id, a.articulo_desc, (round(count(*)/8)) from tickets_yogures a, tickets_yogures b where exists (select *  from tickets_yogures b  where b.articulo_id = 165506 and a.fecha_ticket_id = b.fecha_ticket_id  and a.cliente_id = b.cliente_id)  and a.articulo_id <>165506 group by a.articulo_id) union ....
```

Pero como os decía, para los 85 productos que hay que comprobar, la query se hace muy pesada.

También he probado lo siguiente, para hacer una lista de artículos comprados en cada ticket (hay 85 columnas, una por cada producto creada con GROUP_CONCAT) y 0 o 1 en cada celda dependiendo de si en ese ticket (fila) se ha comprado ese artículo:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
  CONCAT(
  'SUM(CASE WHEN articulo_id = "',
  articulo_id,'" THEN ',1,' ELSE 0 end) AS articuloid_',
  articulo_id)
)
INTO @sql
FROM tickets_prueba;

SET @sql = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE tickets_matriz AS SELECT FECHA_TICKET_ID, cliente_id,', @sql,
              ' FROM tickets_prueba GROUP BY fecha_ticket_id, cliente_id');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;
```

Pero ahora me faltaría el segundo paso que es hacer la matriz en la que cada celda es el sumatorio de la coincidencia del artículo X con el Y.

Comment: Sí. He añadido las pruebas que he hecho. Gracias.